# vuetify - how to center an element inside v-col

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I've been trying to figure out how to center an element inside a v-col for almost an hour
I can't find the right solution.

I am trying to center the a element by putting justify-content in the v-col, but it just stay
there and wont move.

```
<v-row v-if="hideFullDetail">
    <v-col cols="12" md="9" style="justify-content: center;">
      <a @click="displayFullDetail = !displayFullDetail">view more</a>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

[image]

Comment: Does `text-align: center` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align: center` is a property specific for this use case. Works either on the parent, or on the child *itself* if it is a block-level element.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
text-align: center;
```

(This is not specific to v-col).

For details see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP